# Advance LastWriteTime by 6

Tags: powershell, datetime

I have several directories of files which were all created at the same time, but the clocks were not adjusted for time zone. So, I need to increment the LastWriteTime of files in subdirectories by varying times (usually 6-7 hrs) to get the files consistent in time of creation.

Here is a working example.

```cs
Param(
    [String]$fpath = '6-13',
    [Int32]$addhr = 6
)
$fullpath = 'l:\pictures\europetrips\2011\alex\'
$final = -join($fullpath, $fpath)
$fx = Get-ChildItem -Path $final
foreach ($fz in $fx) {
    $fz.LastWriteTime = $fz.LastWriteTime.AddHours($addhr)
}
```

This does modify `LastWriteTime` and adds `$addhr` hours to the time.

All good, except when I view the same directory in Windows Explorer, the timestamps are unchanged. "date" is unchanged. "date modified" is changed. How do I modify "date"?

Comment: You have identified each step you'd like to do, just use those steps, one at a time, in a web search, adding PowerShell to the search string to get to the information to get you on your way. Then as Ansgar says, come back, if you are still having issues. What you are asking for is very basic and lots of examples already exist for each of those all over the web.

Comment: Can't reproduce. Changing the `LastWriteTime` property of a file on my Windows 7 test box updates all related date fields in Windows Explorer (*Date*, *Date modified*, *Date last saved*, ...).

Comment: I have now learned the answer to my question about date not changing. Date WAS not being affected by modifying "date modified" "date last saved". I have learned that Windows10 Explorer gets the date in a PHOTO from the photo information block. All these files are photo files (.jpg), and thus I was correct in that the "overall date" was not being modified. To get at the behavior that I really wanted, I needed to learn how to access the date saved in photo information block.